# Can't enable "number of tests" threshold mode on TestNG Results Plugin plugin

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins 2.73 and TestNG Results Plugin 1.14. And I can't enable "number of tests" threshold mode. I apply and save the job, but "percentage of tests" remains as selected mode...

I want to mark the build unstable if one test fail or skip, but the suite have more than 100 test, because of that I can't use percentage mode.

[image]

Anyone with this issue?

Comment: I tried this on Jenkins **Jenkins ver. 2.78** with **TestNG Results plugin 1.14** and I am able to toggle between both these values.

Comment: I have updated my jenkins and I have reinstalled the plugin. Still the same behaviour, so weird...